# what is -fpermissive error? and How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, loops

15  6   C:\Users\PAUL\Documents\Benson C++\draft hw 2.cpp   [Error] name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

14  5   C:\Users\PAUL\Documents\Benson C++\draft hw 2.cpp   [Note] (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)

```
1  #include <iostream>
2  using namespace std;
3  int main()
4
5  {
6     int num;
7     int ok, ko;
8   
9     cout << "Enter the maximum limit: ";
10    cin >> num;
11  
12    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++);
13
14    {
15    ko= i%2;
16    if(ko==0)
17    cout << "-" << i << endl;
18  
19    ok = i%2>0;
20    if(ok>0)
21    cout <<i<<endl;   
22    }
23  
24  
25    return 0;
26  
27  
28  }
```

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=num;i++);` drop that `;` at the end.

Comment: omg  thank you, I spent 30 mins trying to figure it out.

Comment: crank up compiler warnings